# Select dropdown overlaps confirm() on safari iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

[image: Select overlaps confirm()]

This select is wired to display a confirm dialog when then selection changes

```
  $("#year_select").on("change", function() {...
```

This works fine on all platforms except Safari iOS where the select dropdown stays open on select and overlaps the modal. I have to dismiss the select by tapping on the screen.

Tried to blur() or hide() the select with no result.